# jQuery Click Not Working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

For some reason, this script isn't working in Safari (tested on Windows, think it happens on Mac, too, though):

```
$("#searchTerms").focus(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            $("#searchBtn img").click();
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ux86V/

The script is supposed to click an image when a user presses enter while focused on a search box (it has to be set up this way, it's tied in to some weird third party service).

EDIT: It doesn't appear to work at all in the jsFiddle, but it does, so don't just assume the entire script is bad. I think jSFiddle just prevents redirects, and I have it set up to redirect to google.com for the example.

EDIT 2: It appears to be an issue with `.click()`. Is there an alternative to this that I could use, or is `.click()` the only way to register a click on an element?

EDIT 3: After more testing, it seems like the jQuery click event is somehow not working properly. It may have something to do with the way the form is submitted, I'm not sure. Link to live demo: http://www.weblinxinc.com/beta/blue-sky-marketing/demo/

Comment: Another problem here that might matter is that you're adding a new `keypress` event handler every time the search field gains focus.

Comment: The problem is not the keypress it is the click, see http://jsfiddle.net/ux86V/1/

Comment: Works fine in Safari 5 on Windows: http://jsfiddle.net/ux86V/3/

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/ux86V/4/ click event is fired.

Comment: Why is focus important? Why not skip it and just do `$("#searchTerms").keypress(function() ... `?

Comment: I don't want the page to redirect if they hit enter accidently or something. If they're cursor is focused in the search form and they hit enter then they clearly meant to search. That's not what's causing the problem, I've already tested that.

Comment: I finally figured out that the click() call would work if I called it closer to the user click event or tap on the screen. If I first sent a packet to the server for validation and then called click() when it returned, then it wouldn't work. I have to change my logic or flow.

Answer (score 0):

13 is the code of enter key which is a special key , you can catch it on `keyup` only

Comment: If you run his JSFiddle it catches 13!

Comment: Just tried the keyup thing, it works in Chrome, but not Safari, still.

Comment: @Rev yes keyup instead of keypress

Comment: @Rev wait till i download safari and test it :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `trigger();`

```
$("#searchTerms").focus(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) { 
            $("#searchBtn img").trigger("click");
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Same problem. Nothing happens.

Comment: I think, the problem causes this part of your code: `var link=document.getElementById('reflectedlink'); var input= document.getElementById('searchTerms'); input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {link.search='?searchTerms='+encodeURIComponent(input.value); link.firstChild.data= link.href;};` if you can access to edit this part, try to make this action with jquery, and combine with your other code part about enter keypress thing.